# How to implement radio button in autoform meteorJS

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Schema

```
 Color : {
optional: true,
autoform: {
  type: "select-radio",
  options: function () {
    return [
      {label: "orange", value: orange},
      {label: "blue", value: blue},
      {label: "red", value: red}
    ];
  }
}
```

}

HTML Page:

```
{{> afFormGroup name="Color" type="select-radio" options=options}}
```

The checkbox buttons are not displayed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need a type for you schema field as well. Not just the autoform field. Try this:

```
Color: {
    optional: true,
    type: String,
    autoform: {
        type: "select-radio",
        options: function() {
            return [{
                label: "orange",
                value: orange
            }, {
                label: "blue",
                value: blue
            }, {
                label: "red",
                value: red
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is doing it like this if you want to save some typing (pardon the coffeescript)

```
color:
  type: String
  allowedValues: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Orange']
  autoform:
    type: 'select-radio'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html helper is wrong. The correct way to achieve this is

```
{{> afFormGroup name="Color" type="select-radio" }}
```

Notice that i just removed "options=options" from your original code

```
{{> afFormGroup name="Color" type="select-radio" options=options}}
```